# How can I configure Nginx to use PHP in CGI-mode?

Tags: nginx, php, cgi

The [Nginx tutorial shows PHP 5 being used in FastCGI mode on Windows](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfastcgionwindows/), but PHP 4 doesn't support `php-cgi.exe` so it must be run in traditional cgi mode,

> There are two ways to set up PHP to work with Apache 1.3.x on Windows. One is to use the CGI binary (`php.exe` for PHP 4 and `php-cgi.exe` for PHP 5), the other is to use the Apache Module DLL. In either case you need to edit your httpd.conf to configure Apache to work with PHP, and then restart the server.

Does anyone have a configuration to use PHP 4 in in CGI (not-fastCGI mode on NGINX) I didn't see this in the docs.

Comment: PHP 4 has been end of life for over a decade , was nginx already around then, let alone supporting Windows and php?

Comment: Nginx doesn't support CGI (and never was).

Comment: BTW, nginx on windows still in beta.